# How to keep track of widgets when service is killed?

Tags: android, service, widget

I am trying to fix somebody else's code and would like to have as few mods as possible.  The project is a widget. The way the code is designed, there can be multiple instances of the widget added to the home screen.  There is a service that receives broadcasts for actions in the widgets and deals with the broadcasts accordingly.

As there can be multiple instances of the widget, the service keeps track of the instances using a `HashMap`, mapping widget IDs to actual widgets.  This works quite well until the service is killed (usually from the task manager).  The next time a widget sends a broadcast, the service will be restarted (I haven't spent too much time understanding how it's restarted, but it does).  However in killing/restarting the service, the map of widget IDs to actual widgets gets cleared, therefore the service doesn't know what widget is sending the broadcast and thus doesn't do anything.

What would be the best way to manage this situation?  Somehow save/restore the map maybe?